# Only 1 image instance is displaying

Tags: python, html, django

I installed a logo next to the page title. Using the runserver command in the terminal, the logo image shows up on the homepage, but on subsequent pages (it just displays the alt text for when the image is not working). Any idea why I am running into this error, is it an issue with the html,urls, or view file?

[Homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9kll.png)

[Not Homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjYuu.png)

**base.html:**

```
  <div id="header">
      <img src="\products\2022\03\03\logo.png" >&emsp;<big><font 
color="0c158a"><b><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/">Robo Depot</a></b> 
</font></big>
  </div>
```

**url.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
  from . import views
  from .views import RegisterViewnew , product_list ,LoginView  , 
logoutUser
  app_name = 'shop'

urlpatterns = [
   path('register/', RegisterViewnew.as_view(), name="register_user" 
 ), 
   path('login/', LoginView.as_view() , name="login_page"),
   path('logout/', logoutUser, name="logout"),
   path('', product_list, name='product_list'),
   path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.product_list, 
   name='product_list_by_category'),
   path('<int:id>/<slug:slug>/', 
   views.product_detail,name='product_detail'),
   ]
```

Comment: I doubt it's as simple as replacing your image tag with this, `<img src="logo.jpg" alt="Logo">`, but you did forget the `>` at the end of the img tag, and you don't need the closing `</img>` for this tag (check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element)

Comment: show your base template

Comment: Ok I uploaded it a bit more, I have fixed the error, the logo shows up on all pages now. It was simply just throwing the logo.jpg file into another folder at a lower level (directory wise). The code I uploaded allows the logo to show up (img source), as well as allowing the robo depot text to act as a clickable link that transfers the user to the homepage.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a relative path for your image source. The logo is at `example.com/logo.jpg` (defined by `STATIC_URL` in your settings file) but not at `example.com/not-homepage/logo.jpg`. You should change your `src` to `/logo.jpg/`

Comment: Yah it was a really weird fix; I tried moving the image to the static images folder, and that did not work. I ended up moving the logo to the same folder as the rest of my database images '2022\03\03\logo.png' ... which was 2 levels down directory wise. I don't know why this worked but it did :D

Answer (score 1):

Solution: I moved the image from the highest directory in my files to the lowest directory.